# How to skip teststep in QAF using TestStepListener?

Tags: selenium, bdd, qaf

I am using QAF as my Test Automation Framework.

I want to skip specific teststep in the production environment. How can I skip execution of BDD teststep using TestStepListener?

Here is an example use case:
For shopping cart application I have developed 200+ scenarios. I was executing all scenarios on the test environment. Now I want to execute all scenarios on production environment. Now I want to skip last steps of payment and order review on production environment. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you please provide details of use case? If my understanding is correct you don't want to execute specific step in the production environment. You can use step listener to jump to specific step index but not to skip current step.  One of the way is group steps to high-level step. For example instead of writing detailed steps in bdd

```
Given some situation
When performing some action
Then step-1
And step-2 not for production
and step-3
```

You can have high level step

```
Given some situation
When performing some action
Then generic step for all environments
```

Here your `generic step for all environments` step can have implementation for different environments in different package. configure step provider package at runtime.

Another trick is set and reset dry-run mode in step listener. For example, in your step definition you can provide additional meta-data. In the step listener depends on meta-data if require set dry-run mode in before method and reset it after in method.

Step definition:

```
@MetaData("{'skip_prod':true}")
@QAFTestStep(description = "do payment")
public static void doPayment() {
  //TODO: write your code here 
}
```

Step listener code may look like:

```
public void beforExecute(StepExecutionTracker stepExecutionTracker) {
    Map<String, Object> metadata = stepExecutionTracker.getStep().getMetaData();
    if (null != metadata && metadata.containsKey("skip_prod") && "prod".equalsIgnoreCase(getBundle().getString("env"))) {
       //do not run this step
        getBundle().setProperty(ApplicationProperties.DRY_RUN_MODE.key,true);
    }
}

public void afterExecute(StepExecutionTracker stepExecutionTracker) {
    Map<String, Object> metadata = stepExecutionTracker.getStep().getMetaData();
    if (null != metadata && metadata.containsKey("skip_prod") && "prod".equalsIgnoreCase(getBundle().getString("env"))) {
       // this is not dry run so reset
       getBundle().setProperty(ApplicationProperties.DRY_RUN_MODE.key,false);
    }
}
```